# How to check for null or empty in jq and substitute for empty string in jq transformation

Tags: json, select, jq

How to check for null or empty in jq and substitute for empty string in jq transformation.

Example in below JSON, this is the JQ

JQ:

```
   .amazon.items[] | select(.name | contains ("shoes")) as $item |
   {
        activeItem: .amazon.activeitem,
        item : {
         id : $item.id,
         state : $item.state,
         status : if [[ $item.status = "" or $item.status = null ]]; 
        then 'IN PROCESS' ; else $item.status end
         }  
   }
```

JSON:

```
  {
    "amazon": {
      "activeitem": 2,
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "harry potter",
          "state": "sold"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "adidas shoes",
          "state": "in inventory"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "watch",
          "state": "returned"
        },{
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Nike shoes",
          "state": "in inventory"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I want to add a default string "In Process" if the status is empty or Null.

Based on Item condition, using the query below and take the first object from the filtered results.

`code`
       .amazon.items[] | select(.name | contains ("shoes"))
`code`

Expected Output:

```
{
    "activeitem": 2,
    "item": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "adidas shoes",
      "state": "in inventory",
      "status": "IN PROCESS"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please revise your question in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines, so that it is clear what the requirements for the transformation are.  As things stand, I have no idea where "adidas shoes" comes from, for example.

Comment: @peak, Updated the question.

Comment: The question as a whole is still a bit of a hodge-podge.

Answer (score 9):

The question seems to me self-inconsistent, but under all the interpretations I can think of, the key is to use `|=`:

```
.amazon
| .items[] |= (if (.name | contains ("shoes")) and .status == null 
               then .status="IN PROCESS" else . end)
```

or to select the items with .name containing "shoes":

```
.amazon
| .items |= map(select(.name | contains ("shoes"))
                | if .status == null then .status="IN PROCESS"
                  else . end)
```

Etc.

Comment: Hi Peak, Sorry i didnt get it.. I am trying to transform in this pattern.

Based on Item condition, using the query below.

`code`
.amazon.items[] | select(.name | contains ("shoes"))
`code`

Expected Output:

`code`
        {
          "activeitem": 2,
          "item": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "adidas shoes",
            "state": "in inventory",
             "status": "IN PROCESS"
          }
        }
`code`