# Check if result is an empty string

Tags: json, bash

I have a JSON file which I created using a `jq` command.
The file is like this:

```json
[
  {
    "description": "",
    "app": "hello-test-app"
  },
  {
    "description": "",
    "app": "hello-world-app"
  }
]
```

I would like to have just a simple if/else condition to check if the description is empty.
I tried different approaches but none of them works!!
I tried:

```sh
jq -c '.[]' input.json | while read i; do
description=$(echo $i | jq '.description')
if [[ "$description" == "" ]];
then
  echo "$description is empty"
fi
done
```

and with same code but this if/else;

```sh
if [[ -z "$description" ]];
then
  echo "$description is empty"
fi
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where do you assign a value to the variable $description?

Comment: Do you ever set the variable `$description` or do you assume that bash will search through json files for a matching field?

Comment: @Cyrus I have a loop over the file like this
`jq -c '.[]' input.json | while read i; do
description=$(echo $i | jq '.description')
# here the if...
done `

Comment: Btw.: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: @Cyrus Why is not valid?

Comment: Test it: `jq . input.json`

Comment: There was an illegal trailing comma. I removed it in my edit. It's valid now, and I didn't think that was impacting the thrust of the question.

Comment: Code should be in the question as a [mcve], not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for null or empty in jq and substitute for empty string in jq transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332521/how-to-check-for-null-or-empty-in-jq-and-substitute-for-empty-string-in-jq-trans)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jq [supports conditionals](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ConditionalsandComparisons). No need to bring this back to bash (yet):

```
< foo jq -r '.[] | if .description == ""
                   then "description is empty"
                   else .description end'
description is empty
description is empty
```

If you insist on piping back to bash, here's what is happening:

```
jq -c '.[]' foo | while read i; do description=$(echo $i | jq '.description')
printf '%s\n' "$description"
done
""
""
```

You can see here that the expansion of `$description` is *not empty*. It is literally a pair of quotes each time.

There are several problems with piping to bash here -- the unquoted expansion of `$i`, repiping to `jq` and translating a pair of quotes into a empty string between two different programming languages. But I guess the simple answer is "just test if `"$description"` expands to a pair of quotes."

Testing quotes in bash means quoting your quotes:

```
if [[ $description = '""' ]]; then
    echo '$description expands to a pair of quotes'
fi
```

A better answer is, in my opinion, keep the work in jq.

Comment: thanks. However it is more complex than that. Inside the if I need to write more code. Also, I still don't understand why a simple bash if/else doesn't work.

Comment: @dventi3 if you want to ask about bash, make the question about bash, as simply as possible, by eliminating the unnecessary `jq` part. However, I know from experience that you can do powerful things with only jq...

Comment: @dventi3 it worked for me -- you probably forgot to quote your quotes in the test. See my edit.

Comment: @dventi3 you're welcome. Please reconsider doing this in bash. It's going to be significantly more error prone and hard to maintain that way.

Comment: @dventi3 If you want the raw string without quotes from jq, use `jq -r` (`--raw-output`).